# Creating geospatial pair index in Marklogic with no parent

Tags: indexing, geospatial, marklogic

Is there a way to create a geospatial pair index without the lat long having a parent?

In the documentation, it states that the expected format is {"coords": {
  "lat": 1.0,
  "lon": 2.0
}} 
and then from the Admin Ui for creating the index asks for a parent name. In the above example it would be "coords".

But the data that I am trying to work with has the form 
{
  "lat": 1.0,
  "lon": 2.0
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for geospatial pairs there has to be a parent.

Comment: is there no other way to index data of that form and leverage the geospatial search capability?

Comment: you could use Point format as in: `{ coords: "1.0, 2.0" }`, but you'd have to refactor your data either way..

Comment: @grtjn that is exactly what i did, changed my data structure.